# Can't find the official documentation for the next() method

Tags: node.js, express

I see it is used in various ways: next(), next('route'), next(error)...

Where can I find the official documentation for the `next()` method?

I don't find any documentation summing up it's use cases on the [express api docs](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html)...

**UPDATE:**

From what I coroborated, next works like this:

next() : sends req to the next middleware function of the current route

next('route'): sends req to next matching route

and less obvious...

next(anythingElse) sends req to the next error handling middleware, where err will be equal to anythingElse

Comment: On the docs page that you linked there are 62 occurences (in code and in docs) of the next() method calls. Which use case is your use case that you are missing?

Comment: http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

Comment: @Ma3x: Just wanted to find a doc that sums up the 3 use cases I put in my update. Witch correct me if I'm wrong, isn't in the link I provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can view the "callback" argument under `app.use()` at http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use

There are also middleware callback function examples as well (http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#middleware-callback-function-examples)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at the wrong page in the express documentation. The `next` callback is just to initiate/continue the *request-response* cycle. The actual guide is located under ["Using middleware" title](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) of Guides section on the Expressjs website.

> Middleware functions are functions that have access to the request
>   object (`req`), the response object (`res`), and the next middleware
>   function in the application’s request-response cycle. The next
>   middleware function is commonly denoted by a variable named `next`.
>
> Middleware functions can perform the following tasks:
>
> - Execute any code.
> - Make changes to the request and the response objects.
> - End the request-response cycle.
> - Call the next middleware function in the stack.
>
> If the current middleware function does not end the request-response
>   cycle, it must call `next()` to pass control to the next middleware
>   function. Otherwise, the request will be left hanging.